# Changing view controller from a different class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 views running simultaneously I need to run a method that will create a view on top of both of the already existent views how would I do this from the view that is on the bottom?

(in my case the top view is custom  tab bar that I created and the bottom view is the view for the tab bar and when the user hits a button I wanted to present a model view controller but then it doesn't go over the top view only the bottom view. Is there a way to have method in the tab bar class that can be ran from the bottom view controller class?)

Comment: Instead of adding view to bottom view, add it to `UIWindow`.